# Is insertion sort priority queue-based sorting algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Is insertion sort priority queue-based sorting algorithm? Is heap sort also PQ Based?

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia article on [Priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue#Equivalence_of_priority_queues_and_sorting_algorithms) explains the relationship between priority queues and sorting algorithms:

> #### Using a priority queue to sort
>
> The semantics of priority queues naturally suggest a sorting method: insert all the elements to be sorted into a priority queue, and sequentially remove them; they will come out in sorted order. This is actually the procedure used by several sorting algorithms, once the layer of abstraction provided by the priority queue is removed. This sorting method is equivalent to the following sorting algorithms:
>
> | Name | Priority Queue Implementation | Best | Average | Worst |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Heapsort | Heap | log⁡() | log⁡() | log⁡() |
> | Smoothsort | Leonardo Heap |  | log⁡() | log⁡() |
> | Selection sort | Unordered Array | ² | ² | ² |
> | Insertion sort | Ordered Array |  | ² | ² |
> | Tree sort | Self-balancing binary search tree | log⁡() | log() | log() |

So, yes, you can certainly say that heapsort builds a priority queue (with an efficient implementation). For insertion sort it is less evident, because the priority queue that is being built is actually a sorted sub array. But as a sorted array represents a heap, also insertion sort can be said to build and use a priority queue, but less efficiently. As the queue is a sorted array, the algorithm's "removal" part, quoted above, is not necessary with insertion sort.

Comment: Was this answer useful? Any feed-back?